# Why is my modal not showing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native.

My screen contains 5 buttons, each one opens the same `<Modal>`, but the `<View>` inside it will change depending on the button clicked.

If I click the first button, a text input will be shown into the modal.

If I click the second button, a switch will be shown into the modal.

I've made a modal component (Modal.tsx) :

```
export default class Modal extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.modal} >
        {this.props.children}
      <View>
    )
  };
}

// Specific modal implementation with TextInput
const ModalWithTextInput = props => (
  <Modal>
    <TextInput
      value={props.someValue}
    />
  <Modal>
)


// Specific modal implementation with Switch
const ModalWithSwitch = props => (
  <Modal>
    <Switch
      value={props.someValue}
    />
  <Modal>
)
```

And now in my 5-button-screen (ButtonsScreen.tsx), I open the right modal depending on the button clicked :

```
openTextModal = () => {
   this.setState({ modalType: 'text' });
}

openSwitchModal = () => {
   this.setState({ modalType: 'switch' });
}
```

These functions are called with, for example, `onPress={this.openTextModal}`

Finally, I render the modal, to be able to do something like :

```
<View>
   {this.renderModal(modalType)}
</View>
```

As this :

```
renderModal = (type) => {
    if (type === 'text') {
        return <ModalWithTextInput someValue="default text" />
    }

    if (type === 'switch') {
        return <ModalWithSwitch someValue={false}/>
    }
}
```

When I try to open a modal with onPress={this.openTextModal}, nothing happens (no error, no warning).

Anyone can please help ? Thanks.

Comment: `this.open<type>Modal` will just update the state. You may want to use it then when you renderModal. What is modalType in `{this.renderModal(modalType)}` ? Should it be `{this.renderModal(this.state.modalType)}` ?

Comment: Remove the constructor from the Modal class, it literally does nothing... although it won't fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract modalType from state, in the render method of your component that displays the Modal.

Clicking the button, only set's state, you need to handle state in the component in order to trigger a refresh. A refresh of the render method will render your Modal changes; React 101.

```
render() {
  const { modalType } = this.state;

  return (  
    <View>
      {this.renderModal(modalType)}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Based on the fact that this is pretty much my code from your other question. I strongly suggest you take a step back, learn the basic's of React rather than just asking people to piece together solutions which you do not understand.  Otherwise the result is you learn very little and have code that you do not understand.

Comment: Thank you very much again, Jonathan. I act this way cause I've to finish this for tomorrow (I'm very hurried) then I'll have time to learn the bascis.